# Set prefix discord.py from a .txt file

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

***Hello, today I tried to code a function that retrieves from a file the prefix used for the bot I made***

```
def setprefix():
    with open("prefix.txt") as f:
        prefix = "\n".join(f.readlines())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Bot started. Logged in on Discord BOT Client as {client.user}.')
    activity = discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="le serveur")
    await client.change_presence(activity=activity)
    setprefix()
```

**But when I make a command, I have this error in the console:**

24.02 20:13:10 [Bot] Bot started. Logged in on Discord BOT Client as HELLO#0767.

24.02 20:13:13 [Bot] Ignoring exception in on_message

24.02 20:13:13 [Bot] Traceback (most recent call last):

24.02 20:13:13 [Bot] File "/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event

24.02 20:13:13 [Bot] await coro(*args, **kwargs)

24.02 20:13:13 [Bot] File "/bot.py", line 113, in on_message

24.02 20:13:13 [Bot] if message.content.startswith(prefix+command):

24.02 20:13:13 [Bot] NameError: name 'prefix' is not defined

***Can you help me please ?***

Comment: The name `prefix` is local to `setprefix`. You need to make it global, then call `setprefix` before instantiating the bot, instead of in `on_ready`.

Comment: I changed my code and I called setprefix before instantiating the bot instead of on_ready but, I have the same error.

Comment: `setprefix` does not return the variable or do anything visible outside that function with it. As it is written, it effectively doesn't do anything. If `prefix` is meant to be a global variable, add a `global prefix` statement before you set its value.

Comment: I don't know how to do that

Comment: See my answer, I just gave you two options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's written, `setprefix()` does not return anything or set any value visible outside the function itself.

If `prefix` is meant to be a global variable, you need to declare it so:

```
def setprefix():
    with open("prefix.txt") as f:
        global prefix
        prefix = "\n".join(f.readlines())
```

That's how Python will know that you mean to modify a global variable rather than just create a local variable.

If, instead, it's supposed to return the prefix for `on_ready()` to use, return it:

```
def setprefix():
    with open("prefix.txt") as f:
        return "\n".join(f.readlines())

...
async def on_ready():
    ...
    prefix = setprefix()
    # do stuff with prefix
```